# How to get image src from backend to frontend

Tags: reactjs, frontend, backend

I have 2 folders utalk and server, in my server folder I have a public folder in src folder to save images, that users upload. But I don't know how to get image src from that public folder to display in frontend.(public folder not actually contains image but mp3 instead)

[image: server folder]

[image: utalk folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a lot of context provided. From what i gather, if the folder is public, the resources should be directly accessible. Something like `http://backend/image/file.mp3`.

Also i would recommend using any static file hosting solution for hosting the content file (mp3 in your case). Serving all that content from your http server is a call for performance bottlenecks.

Do add some more context if you are looking for a more specific solution

Comment: oh, thanks for the static file, I've get the image by using it